# Change object using a dictionary as a link

Tags: python

This code:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dog = 'woof'
        self.cats = ['meow']
        print(self.dog, self.cats)
        self.change()
        print(self.dog, self.cats)

    def change(self):
        link = {'dog' : self.dog,
             'cats': self.cats}
        link['dog'] = 'bark'
        link['cats'].append('meow')

a = test()
```

gives me this output:

```
woof ['meow']
woof ['meow', 'meow']
```

When i expected:

```
woof ['meow']
bark ['meow', 'meow']
```

I see that `link['dog'] = 'bark'` just changes the dictionary, not the `self.dog` itself. How do i change where `self.dog` points using dictionary?

Edit:
I don't know wether it's possible or not to do what i want using dictionary, but `setattr()` and `getattr()` would work just fine.

```
def change(self):
    setattr(self, 'dog', 'bark')
    cats = getattr(self, 'cats')
    cats.append('meow')
    setattr(self, 'cats', cats)
```

Comment: `self.dog = 'bark'`? I'd recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You should name your classes with uppercases.

Comment: This is why because by coding this : `{'dog' : self.dog,}` you create key in the dictionary with the value of self.dog not the item itself.

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis, but `self.cats` object has changed!

Comment: Is it necessery to create a dictionary in change function?

Comment: @alexpad: The difference is because the value of `self.dog` in an immutable object, a string, so effectively a copyof it is made. On the other hand `self.cats` is a mutable object, a `list`, so a reference to it is stored in the dictionary...and changes through it also affect the reference to the same `list` stored in the class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want just by using the built-in `link`-like dictionary all class instances have: `self.__dict__`. Here's what I mean:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dog = 'woof'
        self.cats = ['meow']
        print(self.dog, self.cats)
        self.change()
        print(self.dog, self.cats)

    def change(self):
        self.__dict__['dog'] = 'bark'
        self.__dict__['cats'].append('meow')

a = Test()
```

Output:

```
woof ['meow']
bark ['meow', 'meow']
```

Comment: Thanks! Although i'm not completely sure if acessing `__name__` methods is considered ok.

Comment: It's totally fine, especially when it's done in a class method.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted this:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.link = {}
        self.link['dog']  = 'woof'
        self.link['cats'] = ['meow']
        print(self.link['dog'], self.link['cats'])
        self.change()
        print(self.link['dog'], self.link['cats'])

    def change(self):
        self.link['dog'] = 'bark'
        self.link['cats'].append('meow')

a = Test()
```

The difference is in using a dictionary (`link`) in the `__init__` method, too, and to declare it as the *class attribute (variable)*.

Comment: No, i wanted to change `self.dog` and `self.cats` indirectly. Now i see that dictionary way of doing this doesn't always work, but `setattr()` / `getattr()` does. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: If you found a solution, you may answer your own question. - I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want and what you mean by the word *"indirectly"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def change(self):
    self.dog = 'bark'
    self.cats.append('meow')
```

When you do this

```
link = {'dog' : self.dog,
         'cats': self.cats}
```

Only value of `self.dog` and `self.cats` are stored not the actual instances.

Comment: thanks, but i can't dirrectly assign `self.dog` to anything. I've found that `setattr()` would do the trick, though.